# How best to punctuate this sentence?

Tags: punctuation

I have a sentence and am wondering how best to punctuate it. I've included the raw sentence below, as well as my own attempt, and my instructor's suggestion. Any other ideas welcome! I basically feel like the semicolon in my instructor's version breaks up the list too much somehow. What do people here think?

I would probably re-structure the sentence if I had complete freedom to do that, but that wasn't the assignment.

- Raw sentence:

> The following regions were most hit by the storms Venezuela or to be more precise the northern coast of that country Barbados Grenada Trinidad and Tobago.

- My own attempt:

> The following regions were most hit by the storms: Venezuela (or to be more precise, the northern coast of that country), Barbados, Grenada, Trinidad and Tobago.

- My instructor's suggestion:

> The following regions were most hit by the storms: Venezuela, or, to be more precise, the northern coast of that country; Barbados, Grenada, Trinidad and Tobago.

- My 'complete freedom to change everything' version:

> The regions most badly hit by the storms were Barbados, Grenada, Trinidad and Tobago, and the northern coast of Venezuela.

Comment: The "complete freedom" version would be the clearest one, I'd say. Your attempt using brackets would be second-clearest. I also agree with your assessment that the semicolon breaks up the list, which breaks up the reading "flow".

Comment: Some style guides discourage brackets, but the version with all the commas and one semi-colon is weird. Is your instructor a geographer or an English language specialist? I'd certainly prefer "the northern coast of Venezuela" too.

Comment: The sentence looks concocted to test whether you know how to deal with parenthetical remarks.  I agree, your free version is a superior sentence; the parenthetical remark is clumsy there.

Comment: The second one is as clunky as they come. Your own, while certainly an improvement over your instructor's, could be improved further. Settle for the third one. Also, matters related to punctuation are often an "aesthetic" choice.

Comment: The  last one is best.

Comment: Correction of your attempt: `The following regions were hardest hit by the storms: Venezuela (or, to be more precise, the northern coast of that country), Barbados, Grenada, Trinidad and Tobago.` Correction of your instructor's attempt (the first comma is optional): `The following regions were hardest hit by the storms: Venezuela, or, to be more precise, the northern coast of that country; Barbados; Grenada; Trinidad; and Tobago.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your instructor’s version is incorrect; if the semicolon “super comma” is deployed, it must be used for all items:

> *The following regions were most hit by the storms: Venezuela, or, to be more precise, the northern coast of that country; Barbados;
> Grenada; Trinidad and Tobago.*

See Grammar Monster’s [Semicolons in a list](https://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/semicolons_in_lists.htm) for more examples.

(Also, your style guide will likely allow you to omit one or the other of the commas around *or*.)

Without a rewrite, your version works best:

> *The following regions were most hit by the storms: Venezuela (or to be more precise, the northern coast of that country), Barbados,
> Grenada, Trinidad and Tobago.*

Your rewrite is close; it both puts the regions in geographic order and stops *Trinidad and Tobago* from looking like a punctuation fail. Just change *most badly* to *hardest* for idiomatic results:

> *The regions hardest hit by the storms were Barbados, Grenada, Trinidad and Tobago, and the northern coast of Venezuela.*